# $msg contains "test" filter is not dropping events

Tags: rsyslog

I'm attempting to drop events that contain a certain text. I've tried a few different ways, but the events still keep being written to disk.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

**drop.conf**

```
ruleset (name="test_sort") {
        if ($msg contains "test") then {
            stop        
        } else {
            set $!host=$$myhostname;
            action(type="omfile" dynafile="format")
            stop
        }
}

input (type="impudp" port="5000" ruleset="test_sort")
```

I've also tried the following:

```
:msg, contains, "test" stop
```

Comment: FYI for some reason, when test is the first word it doesn't filter. If its not the first word it does filter.

Comment: Could it be that you've tested it using a string like "Test" (uppercase)? In that case you could use `contains_i` which is case-insensitive, unlike `contains`. 
Also you missed a quotation mark in the last line: `input (type="impudp" port="5000" ruleset="test_sort")`. Apart from that the config looks fine to *me*. Note that you can check the syntax with `rsyslogd -N1`.